# Is there any chance to build SXA custom component using Glass mapper?

Tags: sxa, glass-mapper

It may be a very basic question as I'm beginner in sitecore SXA.

Is there any possible way to build the SXA custom component using Glass Mapper?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see any reason why this could be a problem. I saw few people doing it so short answer is **YES**, it is possible,

Comment: Thanks  Alan Płócieniak , If you have any example, can you post it here..

Comment: Yes it is possible - not sure how to combine it with variants though..

Comment: The question should be less of "can you" and more of "should you" - The SXA helpers etc... work off the item a lot - so if you are using any of those, Glass kinda gets in the way - you have to pass the item through anyway. So why bother with the mapping parts - feels like you are duplicating effort at that point. If you are not using variants, then it would probably be ok. But if its variants, I don't see the point.